# Tabulator group/ungroup by column field

Tags: tabulator

At the start, my Tabulatro table is grouped by a column field. I would like to ungroup and show the table in "flat" mode. Is that possible?

Comment: Could you show the sample input and explain clearly how the output should like?

Comment: table.setGroupBy(false)